# Why does $P(u)=u$ hold for projections $P$, $P\circ P=P$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and $P: X\to X$ a bounded projection, so a bounded linear map such that $P(P(v))= P(v)$ for all $v$ in $X$. (From the fact that $P$ is bounded and linear, we can already deduce that $P$ is continuous).

In a solution of an exercise with those projections there was stated that $P(u) = u$ iff $P(P(u))=P(u)$, but this does not make sense for me for two reasons:

1. $P(P(u))=P(u)$ is always true for projections per definition
2. $P(u) = u$ does not seem true, take $P = P_U$ where $U$ is a subspace and $P_U$ is the orthogonal projection on $U$. Take $u$ in $X$ such that $u$ is not an element of $U$, then $Pu$ is in $U$ but certainly not $u$.

Maybe some of you could help me out, this would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You are absolutely right (and this has nothing to do with norm and continuity). Are you really quoting faithfully your book?/printed notes?/web page?

Comment: I think it is a typo for $Pu=u$ if and only if $P(PU)=u$.

Comment: Can you link to the reference?  If this claim was actually made, it looks like a typo.

Comment: The task was to show that ran(P) = im(P) and ker(P) are closed. For kerP this result follows from continuity, and for ran(P) it also follows from continuity observing that ran(P) = ker(Id -P) and Id-P is continuos. So, to show ran(P) = ker(Id-P), it was stated that x is in ker(Id-P) iff Px = x iff P(P(x)) = P(x) iff x is in ran(P). Well, I get that Px=x iff x is in ran(P) (thats simple to show), but I dont get the last to equivalencies

Comment: So you easily proved that if x is in ker(Id-P) then x is in ran(P). I think the rest of your quote is (roughly, whithout equivalences) for the converse: *if* x is in ran(P) *then* x=P(y) for some y, and then P(x)=P(P(y))=P(y)=x, hence x is in ker(Id-P).